# How to compare the ip values in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ip

Input:

```
192.191.0.1
```

List of ip ranges:-

```
192.191.*.*
192.187.*.*
192.213.*.*
192.186.*.*
192.200.*.*
```

`*` => represent 2 or 3 digit numbers

Request URL:-

```
http://www.test.com?ip=192.191.0.1
http://www.test.com?ip=192.200.0.1
http://www.test.com?ip=192.200.0.2
```

I don't want make a request call if request url contains above ip ranges.

How can i put a condition to avoid above ip ranges.

Comment: what do you mean "cancel the request" ?

Comment: @xlembouras I updated the question. Kindly see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`IPAddr`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html) class from the Ruby standard library, for example:

```
require 'ipaddr'

ranges = [
  IPAddr.new('192.191.0.0/16'),
  IPAddr.new('192.187.0.0/16')
]

ranges.any? { |r| r.include?('192.155.0.1') }
# => false

ranges.any? { |r| r.include?('192.191.0.1') }
# => true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you reformat your ranges as follows

```
192.191.1.1/16
192.187.1.1/16
192.213.1.1/16
192.186.1.1/16
192.200.1.1/16
```

you can use the [IPAddr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ipaddr/rdoc/IPAddr.html) class for your checks.

Example:

```
RESTRICTED = ["192.191.1.1/16","192.187.1.1/16"]
RESTRICTED_IPS = RESTRICTED.map { |ip| IPAddr.new(ip) }

target_ip1 = "192.123.231.1"
target_ip2 = IPAddr.new("192.155.0.1")

RESTRICTED_IPS.any? { |ip_range| ip_range.include? target_ip1 }
#=> true

RESTRICTED_IPS.any? { |ip_range| ip_range.include? target_ip2 }
#=> false
```